# What information does UK Immigration store on EEA entrants?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, eu-citizens, identity-cards

When you enter the UK using your EU ID card, what does Immigration store in its system? Does it show exactly when you enter and leave the country by default?

I am just curious - do they write down every time you enter the UK and every time you leave? There is no passport control when you are flying out.

(Added from an answer that did not answer.)
Yes, but when you leave the UK country no one is doing a passport control

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: I am just curious - do they write down every time you enter the UK and every time you leave? There is no passport control when you are flying out.

Comment: @AndrewKaru Yes, the Home Office receives this information from airlines. If you are curious about what specific information they hold about you, you can make a subject access request, now free, thanks to the GDPR. https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/saru

Comment: This is interesting- good to know. By the way “landing cards that we hold electronically” - when you fly out do they have any landing cards? Or  other information that you are out of the country? There is no passport control when you fly out

Comment: @AndrewKaru the UK has, like the US and probably several other countries, a system whereby they collect departing travelers' passport information from airlines.  They match that against entry records (which are also generally opened using passenger data from airlines, and updated when the traveler reaches passport control).

Comment: Fun, I usually enter the UK with my passport through the kiosks/DIY entry things, and leave with my ID card as I book my flights for that.

Answer (score 1):

The [UK guidance immigration and citizenship: privacy information notice](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/710811/border-immigration-citizenship-privacy-information-notice.pdf) explains:

> Personal information supplied or collected for the purposes of entering or
>   leaving the UK, securing the border, making an application for a visa, leave, settlement, citizenship or other immigration service, claiming asylum or other form of protection, or gathered as part of the process of securing the border or enforcing immigration laws will be held and processed by The Home Office[.] This includes when the information is collected or processed by third parties on our behalf.
>
> [Exit Check Fact Sheet](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/exit-checks-on-passengers-leaving-the-uk/exit-checks-fact-sheet)
>
> [E]xit checks will take place at all airports and ports in the UK. Information that is included in passports or travel documents will be collected for passengers leaving the country on scheduled commercial international air, sea and rail routes.

Answer (score 1):

Entries and exits by air are recorded through Advance Passenger Information (API) in the Home Office's *Semaphore* record.

Entries by land/sea, however, are **not** recorded - the officers only retrieve the data from your ID to match against relevant databases etc.

As for exits by land/sea, I'm not sure, but when exiting by train recently there was a Eurostar employee before French border control that swiped documents through a portable scanner in order to transmit data, so I guess those exits are recorded.

As for what is recorded; my records include the airport of entry/exit, flight numbers, booking numbers, time of flight arrival/departure and even the foreign airport I flew from or to